# How to configure wso2 loadbalancer in local machine

Tags: wso2

I am new to wso2. I want to configure wso2 load balancer on my local system and i am planning to test the camel cxf tomcat example.If it possible to test, Please help me to configure the same.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB201/Clustering+with+the+Load+Balancer may helpful.